# Symmetric Matrices with Non-Orthogonal Eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, symmetric-matrices

This is a question from the textbook *Elementary Linear Algebra: Applications Version* which I am struggling with.

> Determine whether there exists a 3 × 3 symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues are λ1 = −1, λ2 = 3, λ3 = 7 and
> for which the corresponding eigenvectors are as stated. If there is
> such a matrix, find it, and if there is none, explain why not.
> \begin{equation*} x_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}, x_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}, x_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \end{equation*}

How do I infer whether or not matrix A is symmetrical without finding matrix A?

I initially said that it was not symmetrical because the eigenvectors are not orthogonal and the eigenvalues are unique. If A were symmetrical, then an orthonormal matrix P could be constructed from its eigenvectors to orthogonally diagonalize A, but I can't see a way to construct this matrix P.

The solutions provided use spectral decomposition to find A and say that A is symmetrical based on this result.
\begin{equation*} A = \lambda_1x_1x_1^T + \lambda_2x_2x_2^T + \lambda_3x_3x_3^T \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{16}{3}&\frac{7}{3}&\frac{7}{3}\\ \:\:\:\:\frac{7}{3}&\frac{11}{6}&\frac{11}{6}\\ \:\:\:\:\frac{7}{3}&\frac{11}{6}&\frac{11}{6}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I thought that it was an assumption of spectral decomposition that A was symmetric?

Is there a mistake in the provided solution or do I not understand a fundamental concept ?

Comment: Your arguments are correct. Probably there's a mistake in the question, maybe $x_3$ should be $(0,1,1)$. Anyway, the matrix $A$ you're showing does not have the prescribed eigenvalues, and $x_2$, $x_3$ are not eigenvectors of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solution is wrong. The matrix has real eigenvalues and a real eigenbasis. Therefore it is a real matrix. If it is symmetric, eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues must be mutually orthogonal. However, $x_2$ is not orthogonal to $x_3$. Therefore $A$ cannot possibly be symmetric.

Even if the three $x_i$s are mutually orthogonal, $A$ is equal *not* to $\sum_i\lambda_ix_ix_i^T$, but to $\sum_i\frac{\lambda_ix_ix_i^T}{\|x_i\|^2}$.